# cannot find a script or extension object associated with namespace in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

I have generated XSLT using altova mapforce and in altova the xslt and output xml is getting generated without any issues.

when i copied the same xslt in visual studio 2013 and trying to run but ended up with below error
**Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:core="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/core" 
  xmlns:vmf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/vmf" 
  xmlns:ns0="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions"   
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="core vmf ns0 xs fn">
    <xsl:template name="core:firstCharacter">
        <xsl:param name="value" select="()"/>
        <xsl:param name="default" select="()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(fn:string-length($value) = xs:integer('0'))">
                <xsl:sequence select="$default"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_cast" as="xs:double" select="xs:double(xs:integer('1'))"/>
                <xsl:sequence select="fn:substring($value, $var1_resultof_cast, $var1_resultof_cast)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_cast" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:decimal('0'))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var2_entry" as="node()?" select="entry"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var3_resultof_map" as="xs:string*">
```

Error at below line:

```
<xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_cast" as="xs:string" select="xs:string(xs:decimal('0'))"/>
```

Comment: Microsoft respectively Visual Studio and the .NET framework use `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`, an XSLT 1.0 processor while your tool generated XSLT 2.0 code which does not work with an XSLT 1.0 processor. You would need to use third party XSLT 2.0 implementations like XmlPrime or like the .NET version of Saxon 9 if you want to use XSLT 2.0 in .NET or VS.

Comment: Or rewrite your transformation code in the XSLT 1.0 language.